# Is DirectoryStream faster than Files.listFiles()?

Tags: java

I am new to DirectoryStream and learning it now.
I saw this quote

> However, Java 7 introduced a faster alternative to File#listFiles called DirectoryStream.

And decided to test it with a simple code.

```
 public class Testing {
   static Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dmitry\\Downloads");


// Method using File.listFiles
public static Set<String> listFilesUsingJavaIO(String dir) {
    return Stream.of(new File(dir).listFiles())
            .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
            .map(File::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}




// Method using DirectoryStream
    public static Set<String> listFilesUsingDirectoryStream(String dir) throws IOException {
        Set<String> fileList = new HashSet<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(dir))) {
            for (Path entity : stream) {
                if (!Files.isDirectory(entity)) {
                    fileList.add(entity.getFileName()
                            .toString());
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.now(); 

    Set<String> setik = listFilesUsingDirectoryStream(dir.toString());
    System.out.println(setik);
    LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.now(); 
    long seconds = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(ldt1,ldt2);

System.out.println(seconds); // Difference in time
    }
}
```

I have two methods. One - using File.listFiles(), another - DirectoryStream.
Executed them multiple times and always got the same result - Stream with File.listFiles was faster.
I am really interested, what am I doing wrong and what is the point of DirectoryStream, if Stream with File.listFiles() works better.

I do appreciate your answers a lot!

Comment: You should compare results with directories containing very few and very many files, and drop the isDirectory calls in both tests as they add a filesystem access per item which will skew all your timings of listFiles+newDirectoryStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have directories with many thousands of files, `File#listFiles()` will take a while as it will have to enumerate all the files and construct the array to return. `DirectoryStream` will start returning files as it reads the directory.

If your app doesn't need the entire file listing (e.g. if it's looking for any file matching some criteria) then `DirectoryStream` could be dramatically faster.

Comment: ```DirectoryStream``` is faster. Especially if your are reading a non-local drive such as a NAS. I found it to be about twice as fast for large listings (500+ files). No metrics, just an impression.